# Broadcasting message to multiple JMS (point-to-point message queue) using Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

Currently i have a working spring integration Project which send Message to one instance of ActiveMQ's queue. Its Uses serviceActivator as an endpoint where the handler is JMSSendingMessageHandler.java. The model is shown below:

client--->request CHannel--->Service Activator(Endpoint).

But now i want to send message to multiple instance of ActiveMQ which will be configured in the configuration file. In spring Integration , no out-of-box solution is available.
The diagram of my requirement is given below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do3wu.png)

i Need to findout, how to create multiple Service Activators in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is out-of-the-box solution and it is called `publish-subscribe-channel`.
And your diagram demonstrates exactly the case:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel

So, you create as many service-activators as you need, for all those ActiveMQ's queue and configure their `input-channel` to the same `publish-subscribe-channel`.

Please, elaborate more about that "in runtime" requirement.

Comment: We are trying to build a reusable component, using which other application can send same message to multiple MQ. by runtime, i mean that, We need to create service-activator based on the configurations available in the yml file.

Comment: OK. You can take a look into Spring Integration Java DSL runtime flows registration: https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/27/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-candidate-1-is-available

Comment: Why do you tell me that? That doesn't looks like an info I should pay attention...

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply . I submitted the incomplete query by mistake. Anyways, I checked the code mentioned in the link
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/dynamictcp/DynamicTcpClientApplication.java

Can u please tell me how to create bean inOne and inTwo dynamically.

Comment: The `IntegrationFlowRegistrationBuilder` returned from the `integrationFlowContext.registration(...)` has `addBean()` on the matter.